# Can we add comments in table in oracle DB?

Tags: oracle

Can we add comments in table like what it is doing?

I know that we can add comments to column and we can check that comment in user_col_comments table?

But can we add comments in table to specify its purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can comment on a table, column, operator, indextype, or materialized view, using the same sort of syntax:

```
comment on table my_schema.my_table is 'This is my comment';
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4009.htm